# Custom renderer crashes QGIS because "renderFeature" is called in a different thread

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am trying to implement a custom renderer with Python in QGIS. I have put together a small toy example based on the code from the [Creating Custom Renderers](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#creating-custom-renderers) section of the PyQGIS Cookbook.

To get this code to work, I had to override the `renderFeature` function from the `QgsFeatureRenderer` class. I believe this should not be necessary, because I am essentially just re-implementing the [original implementation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRenderer.html#af9597fb1d6b605d0b35733dd2f464b43). However, if I remove the implementation of `renderFeature` from my code and try to use the renderer in a version of QGIS that was built using `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, the following assert failure is thrown:

`Fatal: ASSERT failure in QgsFeatureRenderer::renderFeature: "renderFeature called in a different thread - use a cloned renderer instead", file ../src/core/symbology/qgsrenderer.cpp, line 122`

Note that in a QGIS version without the `Debug` build type, the code works even with the `renderFeature` function removed. I assume the assertion is there for a reason, though, so ignoring this seems like the wrong thing to do.

What am I missing? Which renderer do I have to clone to avoid this error?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a version of QGIS built with the `Debug` build type
2. Paste the code below into the Python console and hit Enter
3. Load a points layer
4. In the layer styling panel, select the `Test renderer`
5. QGIS should crash

```py
from qgis.core import QgsWkbTypes, QgsSymbol, QgsFeatureRenderer
from qgis.gui import QgsRendererWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor


class TestRenderer(QgsFeatureRenderer):
    def __init__(self):
        QgsFeatureRenderer.__init__(self, "TestRenderer")
        self.sym = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(QgsWkbTypes.geometryType(QgsWkbTypes.Point))
        self.sym.setColor(QColor('blue'))

    def symbolForFeature(self, feature):
        return self.sym

    def startRender(self, context, vlayer):
        self.sym.startRender(context)

    ####
    # The following function is basically identical to the default implementation of renderFeature
    # However, if I don't implement it here, QGIS crashes and I get the following
    # error message:
    # "renderFeature called in a different thread - use a cloned renderer instead"
    ####
    #def renderFeature(self, feature, context, layer, selected, drawVertexMarker):
    #   s = self.symbolForFeature(feature)
    #   s.renderFeature(feature, context, layer, selected, drawVertexMarker)
    #   return True

    def stopRender(self, context):
       self.sym.stopRender(context)

    def usedAttributes(self, context):
        return []

    def clone(self):
        return TestRenderer()


class TestRendererWidget(QgsRendererWidget):
    def __init__(self, layer, style, renderer):
        QgsRendererWidget.__init__(self, layer, style)
        if renderer is None or renderer.type() != "TestRenderer":
            self.r = TestRenderer()
        else:
            self.r = renderer

    def renderer(self):
        return self.r


from qgis.core import QgsRendererAbstractMetadata, QgsApplication


class TestRendererMetadata(QgsRendererAbstractMetadata):
    def __init__(self):
        QgsRendererAbstractMetadata.__init__(self, "TestRenderer", "Test renderer")

    def createRenderer(self, element):
        return TestRenderer()

    def createRendererWidget(self, layer, style, renderer):
        return TestRendererWidget(layer, style, renderer)


QgsApplication.rendererRegistry().addRenderer(TestRendererMetadata())
```

Comment: You need to call the base class (super) implementations of startRender, stopRender, usedAttributes, in your overrides

Comment: @ndawson: Fantastic, that did the trick! Adding `super().startRender(context)` and `super().stopRender(context)` fixes the problem. Adding `_ = super().usedAttributes(context)` to the `usedAttributes` override causes a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`, which I assume happens because `usedAttributes` is a pure virtual function that does not have an implementation in the base class. Leaving the override as is (simply `return []`) works fine though. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 2):

As ndawson explained in [his comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331677/custom-renderer-crashes-qgis-because-renderfeature-is-called-in-a-different-th?noredirect=1#comment541280_331677), the `startRender` and `stopRender` implementations of the base class need to be called in the overrides. The following code now works, without the need to reimplement the `renderFeature` function.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsWkbTypes, QgsSymbol, QgsFeatureRenderer, QgsRendererAbstractMetadata, QgsApplication
from qgis.gui import QgsRendererWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor


class TestRenderer(QgsFeatureRenderer):
    def __init__(self):
        QgsFeatureRenderer.__init__(self, "TestRenderer")
        self.sym = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(QgsWkbTypes.geometryType(QgsWkbTypes.Point))
        self.sym.setColor(QColor('yellow'))

    def symbolForFeature(self, feature, xx):
        return self.sym

    def startRender(self, context, fields):
        # Call QgsFeatureRenderer's startRender function
        super().startRender(context, fields)

        self.sym.startRender(context, fields)

    def stopRender(self, context):
        # Call QgsFeatureRenderer's stopRender function
        super().stopRender(context)

        self.sym.stopRender(context)

    def usedAttributes(self, context):
        return []

    def clone(self):
        return TestRenderer()


class TestRendererWidget(QgsRendererWidget):
    def __init__(self, layer, style, renderer):
        QgsRendererWidget.__init__(self, layer, style)
        if renderer is None or renderer.type() != "TestRenderer":
            self.r = TestRenderer()
        else:
            self.r = renderer

    def renderer(self):
        return self.r


class TestRendererMetadata(QgsRendererAbstractMetadata):
    def __init__(self):
        QgsRendererAbstractMetadata.__init__(self, "TestRenderer", "Test renderer")

    def createRenderer(self, element):
        return TestRenderer()

    def createRendererWidget(self, layer, style, renderer):
        return TestRendererWidget(layer, style, renderer)


QgsApplication.rendererRegistry().addRenderer(TestRendererMetadata())
```